# Ratio of heads to tails as number of tosses increases

Tags: probability

The question was asked in last year exam and I am little confused about it.
The question is

In an experiment, with increasing number of tosses of a coin the

(1) Ratio of heads to tails approaches 1 and also the differential count between heads and tails declines.

(2) Ratio of heads to tails approaches 1 while the differential count between heads and tails increases.

(3) The ratio of heads and tails oscillates around 1 while the differential count between them declines.

(4) The ratio of heads to tails remains at 1.

Firstly I am not getting what does 'differential count between heads and tails means'.
Second, I think the ratio should approach 1 but again it also sounds correct that it will oscillate around 1. Which option is correct then?

Thanks.

Comment: Differential count probably means "number of heads minus number of tails."

Comment: So it will neither decline nor increase.. will oscillate around zero right?

Comment: Actually it is possible that it means the absolute value of the difference. I am not sure though, I am not familiar with this terminology.

Comment: I would actually expect the differential to increase. And I agree with @angryavian, it is probably the latter definition.

Comment: @Gregory Why you think differential count should increase? Ratio will approach 1 no..

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_n$ be the number of heads in $n$ tosses. the ratio of heads to tails is $\frac{X_n}{n-X_n} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{X_n/n} - 1}$. Now apply the law of large numbers to explain the behavior of $X_n/n$, and then apply the continuous mapping theorem to explain how the above ratio behaves.

---

The "differential count" between heads and tails is $|X_n - (n-X_n)| = 2|X_n - (n/2)|$. The random variables $X_n$ is approximately has mean $n/2$ and variance $n/4$, so $2|X_n - (n/2)|$ has fluctuations around zero of order $\sqrt{n}$, which grows with $n$.

Comment: That's looks some advance probability stuff.. we have basic probability only in our syllabus.. idk why they ask this question 

Comment: @Believer In that case, try simulating coin flips and see how $X_n$ and $X_n/n$ behave. You will see that the distribution $X_n$ will be centered at $n/2$ but can be quite spread out, whereas $X_n/n$ will converge to $0.5$.

Comment: Ok.. ty.. I will try.. so option 2 is the correct choice, right?